# How to explain reasons for leaving to people who recommended you

Tags: management, resignation, references

I quit my job today which I joined 6 months back. I was "highly-recommended" for this job by some senior executives of the company with whom I had worked before. (Same company but several years back and different office in a different country). These executives from main office are not involved in offshore regional office or know the management personally. They just sent their strong recommendation. Because of this recommendation, my interview was short and smooth. I loved the culture and people of previous office and hence I accepted this one.

However, I could not survive here for long because the job did not turn out anywhere close to what I was promised during the interview(Pay was good but my role and team were changed significantly). I had several disagreements with the management of this office over last 6 months on my role. Finally I decided to leave.

I left in good terms and I made my reasons clear in as professional way I can during exit interview. Now I am not sure how to tell this to the people who recommended me. I feel that I owe them an explanation because they vouched for me. At the same time I cannot explain why I left without ranting or complaining. They have no context on what I was offered, what I was expecting and what happened here.

So my question is **how do I communicate to the people who recommended me without any indication of blame/complains or any kind of ranting? Should I apologize to them at all?**  (Although I do not think I did anything wrong and the local management messed up). I just want to maintain relationship with them professionally without whining about events from past.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I don't think you need to take this any further with anyone. You made it clear to the company you were working for *why* you are leaving and that should be enough. Only if the people that recommended you approach you would I say anything.

> *At the same time I cannot explain why I left without ranting or complaining.*

This is exactly why I wouldn't say anything. It's never good to complain about a job no matter how bad it was at times and instead you should only leave with the positives.

If you really wanted to say something to those that recommended you just keep it brief. Something similar to:

> I wanted to let you know that I have now left [company name] as it was not what I expected. I wanted to thank you for your strong recommendations and hope we can maintain a professional relationship.

<sup>You may want to alter the wording but I really would keep it brief. There's no need to go into a lot of detail.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

> how do I communicate to the people who recommended me without any
>   indication of blame/complains or any kind of ranting? Should I
>   apologize to them at all?

You don't need to explain your reasons for leaving unless these people ask.

If they do ask, you can always be honest, but not rant. Something like this:

"The job did not turn to be what I had hoped for during the interview." and leave it at that.

You don't need to apologize. You didn't do anything wrong.

You could thank them for their recommendation, even though it didn't ultimately work out. These things happen. Most people understand that.